# TP-Link wn822n drivers

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, adapter

So I purchased a TP-Link wn822n usb wireless adapter, but I can't find a driver for it.  It works for like 5 minutes out of the box, but then stalls out.  I found one here in the forums, but it was outdated.  I need a driver for version 3.0 of the product.  I am new to ubuntu so I'm really lost right now, as I really want this adapter to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered issues with TP-Link WN822N also. The exact model was "TL-WN822N".

On Ubuntu 18.04 this previous solution worked for me:
[How to install TP link WN822N on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832087/how-to-install-tp-link-wn822n-on-ubuntu)

That solution uses the drivers at: https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

However, it does not compile on Ubuntu 20.04 as it appears not to have been maintained to work with the latest kernel.

The following repository did work for me on 20.04:
https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

Follow the instructions exactly as written in the README.

Before: speed test ~5 Mbps
After: speed test >60 Mbps

Answer (score 0):

New to linux for the last 3 hours
Clicked https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
downloaded the code
saved on desktop
right clicked on it -> Open in terminal
I typed make hit enter,
did its work... took some time
and then from the page i downloaded the code, I copied and paste in terminal steps from 2 and bellow starting from the second line -> cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver;

I don't have any idea what I did, but it worked. I hope this will help others